# Is it possible to append data to a PDF page with modifying the original page object

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm trying to append some data to a page of a PDF, by using the PDF versioning system (e.g. appending data to the end of a valid PDF with it's own XREF and what not).

Right now I'm just attempting to do a proof of concept. I can append an orange square to an existing page, but it requires me to parse out the original page object, alter the Contents array, and add that the data I'm appending. Example:

Original Page:

```
5 0 obj
<<
/Parent 4 0 R
/Contents[2 0 R 8 0 R 3 0 R]
/Type
  /Page
/Resources
  <<
  /ExtGState
    <<
    /GSa 6 0 R
    >>
  /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
  /XObject
    <<
    /Im9 9 0 R
    >>
  /ColorSpace
    <<
    /CSp/DeviceRGB/CSpg/DeviceGray/PCSp 7 0 R
    >>
  /Font
    <<
    /F11 10 0 R
    /F6 11 0 R
    /Xi0 1 0 R
    >>
  >>
/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]
/Annots 12 0 R
>>
endobj
```

Modified page:

```
5 0 obj
<<
/Parent 4 0 R
/Contents[2 0 R 8 0 R 3 0 R 2 0 R 901 0 R 3 0 R]
/Type
  /Page
/Resources
  <<
  /ExtGState
    <<
    /GSa 6 0 R
    >>
  /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
  /XObject
    <<
    /Im9 9 0 R
    >>
  /ColorSpace
    <<
    /CSp/DeviceRGB/CSpg/DeviceGray/PCSp 7 0 R
    >>
  /Font
    <<
    /F11 10 0 R
    /F6 11 0 R
    /Xi0 1 0 R
    >>
  >>
/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]
/Annots 12 0 R
>>
endobj
```

As you can see, I'm just altering the Contents array to insert my own data (an orange square with the object ID "901").

Is it possible to achieve the same result without parsing & modifying the original page object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the /Contents array is a direct object, the entire page object is modified so you have to parse the page object and rewrite it with the new /Contents array.

If the /Contents would have been an indirect object then you could have modified only the array without touching the page object.